# How can I do this: text inside rectangle using HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css

Hello I want to do this in HTML/CSS can you help me please?

[image]

I tried to do this:

Here is my css code:

```
    .line-lg{
   width:120%; 
   text-align: center; 
   border-bottom: 2px solid #000; 
   line-height: 0.1em;
   margin: 10px 0 20px; 
}

.line-lg span{
  background:#4e5d6c; 
    padding:0 10px; 
}

.rectangle{
padding-top: 40px;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid #000; 
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Here is my html code:

```
<table class="table">
   <tr>
      <td>
         <div class="rectangle">
            <h4 class="line-lg"><span>Lol</span></h4>
         </div>
      </td>
      <td>
         <div class="rectangle">
            <h4 class="line"><span>Lol</span></h4>
         </div>
      </td>
      <td>
         <div class="rectangle"></div>
         <h4 class="line"><span>Lol</span></h4>
         </div>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

The result I have is this:

[image]

As you can see the line is not filling all the space and I don't know how to make this I have tried to make some other things without success so I have no idea how to do it. I am little new in HTML/CSS so if you could give me some advice I really appreciate it

Comment: why -1? I don't understand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do this

```css
.parent {
    width: 500px;
    height: 140px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: slategray;
}
.container {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 30px;
    text-align: justify;
    font-size: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: absolute;
}
.lol {
    font-size: 14px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    text-align: center;
}
.container:after {
    content:'';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
.lol span {
    line-height: 80px;
    background-color: slategray;
    padding: 4px;
}
.line {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 70px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="lol"><span>LOL</span></div>
        <div class="lol"><span>LOL</span></div>
        <div class="lol"><span>LOL</span></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't work for IE, it seems the align justified is not working see: https://jsfiddle.net/bajocero/vqjqq08v/1/